# In Uno, can you play a Wild Draw 4 Card when you have another Wild Card in your hand?

Tags: uno

My wife insists that if you have a Wild Card in your hand you cannot play the Wild Draw 4 Card because the first Wild Card constitutes having the same color card as the one on the Discard pile.

I say it does not as a Wild Card can be any color you choose when you play it.
Who is correct?

Answer (score 14):

According to the [rules sheet from Mattel](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf):

> You may only play this card when you do NOT have another card in your hand that matches the COLOR on the DISCARD pile (but it is acceptable to play this card if you have matching number or Action Cards).

Since Wild cards are classified as Action cards, you are legally allowed to play a Wild Draw Four when you have a Wild in hand.