# My friend put wild color card. It was my turn after her. Can I put another wild color card?

Tags: uno

My friend put wild color card. It was my turn to put. Is it possible to put another wild color card?

Comment: It is possible anyway. _Assumptions_

Answer (score 14):

According to [this website](http://www.unorules.com/), the rules for Wild cards state (emphasis mine):

> This card represents all four colors, **and can be placed on any card**. The player has to state which color it will represent for the next player. It can be played regardless of whether another card is available.

So yes, a player may place a Wild on the pile in response to a Wild.  However, if the card is a Wild +4, that player must have no cards of the color declared by the previous player, and may be challenged.

Comment: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/30280/10217 agrees, I believe those are the official rules.